# C# Observable / Notify ListView ColumnHeaderCollection activity

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am writing an extended ListView control and I would need to watch/subscribe to events when a Column is added/modified/removed. - This is WinForms C# 12 .NET 8

As far as I have seen, the ColumnHeaderCollection returned by listview.Columns does not support that, does anyone know how I can override this and still return a ColumnHeaderCollection on the Columns property? I want to retain their default functionalities like ContainsKey, RemoveByKeys and all the constructurs.

If I overload this with a regular List I lost all that.

Comment: So don't use a regular `List`. Define your own custom collection that inherits `Collection<T>`. That way, you can do anything you want when items are added or removed, including raising events and modifying the control's standard column collection, and you can also add any other members you want, thus mimicking what the original collection had.

Comment: But ColumnHeaderCollection implements IList, and exposes lots of new methods that I would like to keep, without overriding/writing them again.

Comment: You can't have everything you want. If `ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection` doesn't support the functionality you need then you can't use it, so complaining that it has other functionality you want doesn't benefit anyone. If you define your own custom collection as a facade to the existing collection then at least each of the methods you need to reproduce will only require one line to invoke the corresponding method in the existing collection. It's up to you: do a little extra work or do without the functionality you want.

Comment: You can replace the `ColumnHeaderCollection` with a custom, derived, one. You have to use Reflection to get the `_columnHeaderCollection` Field (since it's `readonly private`) and call `.SetValue()` to replace it. You need to do that in the Constructor of your ListView, and also shadow (`new`) the `Columns` property, to return your own `ColumnHeaderCollection` -- All the `Add()`, `Remove()` etc. methods are overridable, so you can raise an event when one of these methods are called. You can also bubble up these events in your Control, raising custom public events, if necessary

Comment: If you do that, mind that Columns added in the Designer are generated from Resources. So, while testing your custom Control, make sure that, when you change something in its class, you remove any Column added in the Designer, then delete the Control and replace it with a new one, after you have rebuilt the Project. Failing to do so may compromise the Resources of the Project you're working on. I suggest you perform any test in a side Project that you can delete, if anything goes wrong

Comment: Is it design-time or runtime question? If you mean adding events to be raised when you add/delete columns at runtime, then you can trap the `HDM_INSERTITEM` and `HDM_DELETEITEM` of the [Header Control Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bumper-header-control-reference-messages) to notify the parent (`ListView`) which raises the appropriate events for a subscriber to consume. No?

Comment: @dr.null that did the trick, I was able to intercept the right Msgs and then keep an internal list, HDM_INSERTITEM gets called more than once for every column you insert, thats weird, but I sorted it out, thanks a lot !!!